retrieve list of urls from Amazon S3 bucket using R
I'm trying to scrape all tif urls from a public facing website (https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/). I receive a list of tif urls back, but it only returns 1000, when there are 15,626.
library(tidyverse)
library(RCurl)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

start_url <- 'https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/'

files <- read_html(gsub('index\\.html\\?','?delimiter=/&', start_url)) %>% 
  html_elements('key') %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  url_absolute(start_url)

length(files)

[1] 1000

There should be 15,626 files (or urls).

You'll need to make multiple calls, passing in the value from NextMarker as key-marker while IsTruncated is true.

You could always use paws. Paws is an aws sdk for R.
library(paws)

client <- s3()

bucket <- "prd-tnm"
prefix <- "StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF"

# list all elements in bucket and prefix:
# paginate over all pages to get all keys
keys <- client$list_objects_v2(
  Bucket = bucket,
  Prefix = prefix
) |> paginate_lapply(\(resp) {
  vapply(resp$Contents, \(pg) pg$Key, FUN.VALUE = "")
}) |> unlist()

length(keys)
#> [1] 15627

# create s3 uris
sprintf("s3://%s/%s", bucket, keys)[1:5]
#> [1] "s3://prd-tnm/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514270.tif"
#> [2] "s3://prd-tnm/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514271.tif"
#> [3] "s3://prd-tnm/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514272.tif"
#> [4] "s3://prd-tnm/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514273.tif"
#> [5] "s3://prd-tnm/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514274.tif"

# create https urls links
sprintf("https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s", bucket, keys)[1:5]
#> [1] "https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514270.tif"
#> [2] "https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514271.tif"
#> [3] "https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514272.tif"
#> [4] "https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514273.tif"
#> [5] "https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Elevation/OPR/Projects/MN_RainyLake_2020_B20/MN_RainyLake_1_2020/TIFF/USGS_OPR_MN_RainyLake_2020_B20_15TWN514274.tif"

Created on 2024-09-25 with reprex v2.1.1
I hope this helps
